# Modify this auto tab-closing script to work with multiple tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, tampermonkey

So...

I have like 100 Tabs open in Google Chrome, and i need to automatically close those tabs that contain the words "Status  97%" and "Status  96%" in its visible Text.

If you write me a working script, i would even pay you a generous amount, i mean it !

Can someone help me write something that i can just copy-paste into tampermonkey for example so that i can use it ?
i can modify code a little bit, but i am not able to write it myself, im not good enough yet...

So i need help please..

I tried a script from github:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      Autoclose Tab
// @namespace Autoclose Tab
// @include   *
// ==/UserScript==

// separate words or phrases with a comma
var blacklist = ["cactus", "finances", "put other text here"],
    re = new RegExp(blacklist.join('|'), "i");
if (re.test(document.body.textContent)) {
  var win = window.open("","_self");
  win.close();
}
```

but it does NOT work for me somehow... (yes i replaced the word "cactus" with "Status 97%" , etc...  i can see this script IN the tampermonkey extension, and i can click on it to activate this script, but it doesnt do anything, i dont know why)
and i think it would anyways only close ONE tab at a time, but i need multiple tabs to be checked and closed...

So whoever helps me here, i would pay you !
Thanks

Comment: See: [`window.close()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:window.close).